# magento : show image before xml elements

Tags: xml, magento

I am creating magento admin module. Basically I want to show an image(icon) before the title of that module.

I want to achieve like this
[image]

I have tried with following code but no luck :(

```
<title><![CDATA[<img src="media/icon.png"/>]]>Title</title>
```

which outputs like this
[image]

----------edit -----

I tried to rewrite Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu but no success

```
public function getMenuLevel($menu, $level = 0)
    {
        $html = '<ul ' . (!$level ? 'id="nav"' : '') . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($menu as $index => $item) {
            $html .= '<li ' . (!empty($item['children']) ? 'onmouseover="Element.addClassName(this,\'over\')" '
                . 'onmouseout="Element.removeClassName(this,\'over\')"' : '') . ' class="'
                . (!$level && !empty($item['active']) ? ' active' : '') . ' '
                . (!empty($item['children']) ? ' parent' : '')
                . (!empty($level) && !empty($item['last']) ? ' last' : '')
                . ' level' . $level . '"> <a href="' . $item['url'] . '" '
                . (!empty($item['title']) ? 'title="' . $item['title'] . '"' : '') . ' '
                . (!empty($item['click']) ? 'onclick="' . $item['click'] . '"' : '') . ' class="'
                . ($level === 0 && !empty($item['active']) ? 'active' : '') . '">'

                ////////////edits

                . ($index == 'modulename' ? $item['label'] : '<span>' 
                . $this->escapeHtml($item['label']) . '</span></a>' . PHP_EOL;

            if (!empty($item['children'])) {
                $html .= $this->getMenuLevel($item['children'], $level + 1);
            }
            $html .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $html .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        return $html;
    }
```

here is config.xml menu part

```
 <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <company module="modulename" translate="title">
                <title><![CDATA[<span class="module-icon">Company</span>]]></title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <modulename translate="title" module="modulename">
                        <title>Theme Options</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <configuration>
                                <title>Configuration</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/modulename</action>
                            </configuration>
                        </children>
                    </modulename>
                </children>
            </company>
        </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Where does the `$index` variable come from in your rewrite code ?

Comment: sorry it was for  "foreach ($menu as $index => $item) " and I now using <![CDATA[<span class="mudule-icon">Modulename</span>]]> in config.xml but no luck :(

Comment: Do `<span class="mudule-icon">Modulename</span>` still get escaped ? What result do you get currently ?

Comment: Currently I am getting same `<span class="mudule-icon">Modulename</span>`

Comment: Have you tested if the specific value of `$index` is the good one ? (can you paste the entire menu definition from config.xml in your question ?) And have you tested if the menu block is actually rewritten ?

Comment: sure i will post. but how to chk if the menu block is actually rewritten ?

Comment: You can eg alter the rendering by returning `''` in `getMenuLevel()` or concatenating a given character after `$this->escapeHtml($item['label'])`. If this has an effect then the block is rewritten.

Comment: ok can you chk edited post

Comment: Given your menu configuration, can you test with `$index == 'company'` instead of `'modulename'` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually block was not being rewritten..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin menu is generated by the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` block, which escapes HTML from titles (see `getMenuLevel()`). If you want to add images in titles, you'll need to rewrite this block in order to remove this behaviour.